# Counting similarity of arrays inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem where I am pretty unsure how to solve this.

Given are arrays in such a format:

```
$array01 = array(
    0 => array("hallo", "welt", "du", "ich"),
    1 => array("mag", "dich"),
    2 => array("nicht", "haha", "huhu")
);

$array02 = array(
    0 => array("haha", "welt", "dich"),
    1 => array("hallo", "mag", "nicht"),
    2 => array("du", "ich", "huhu")
);
```

Now I want to calculate some kind of similarity value of these arrays. These arrays are the result of clustering terms according to their meaning.

What I want to know is how similar these terms are clustered by two different users `($array01 = user1, $array02 = user2)`. 0,1,2 are those clusters (they don't have to be the same length)

EDIT: 
So i try to describe a little bit further:
Every array is a result of a user clustering the terms (hallo, welt, du, ich...) according to their meaning. So every sub-array is one cluster defined by the user. Now the problem is that the user is not restricted in where he places a term or the whole cluster, so i cannot just compare $array01[0] with $array02[0]. 
I guess i need to compare the sub-arrays with the most terms in common. Every user HAS to cluster all terms though.

So for example:

$array01[0] and $array02[2]. They have 2 terms in common: "du" and "ich" -> +1

The other terms have no clear clustering, so i would guess this example would yield 1, because the clusterings are not very similar.

Comment: So any word from user1, can be in any other subarray of user2?

Comment: can you be more specific about what you are wanting to compare and what you mean by compare? For example, do you just want to compare all the values of the nested arrays between `$array01` and `$array02` and see how many mutual values there are? Do you only want to compare 0 to 0, 1 to 1, etc.?

Comment: can you please post the expected result for the example you gave?

Comment: I tried to describe the problem a little bit better...look for my edit.

Comment: So do you want a Matrix result of how many terms overlap of subArary?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

---

## get_similar_items

Code:

```
<?php

$array01 = array(
    0 => array("hallo", "welt", "du", "ich"),
    1 => array("mag", "dich"),
    2 => array("nicht", "haha", "huhu")
);

$array02 = array(
    0 => array("haha", "welt", "dich"),
    1 => array("hallo", "mag", "nicht"),
    2 => array("du", "ich", "huhu")
);

function get_similar_items() {
    $arrs = func_get_args();
    foreach ($arrs as &$arr) {
        while (list($k, $v) = each($arr)) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                array_splice($arr,$k,1,$v);
                next($arr);
            }
        }
    }
    return call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$arrs);
}

print_r(get_similar_items($array01,$array02));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hallo
    [1] => welt
    [2] => du
    [3] => ich
    [4] => mag
    [5] => dich
    [6] => nicht
    [7] => haha
    [8] => huhu
)
```

---

## get_similar_items_count

Code:

```
<?php

$array01 = array(
    0 => array("hallo", "welt", "du", "ich"),
    1 => array("mag", "dich"),
    2 => array("nicht", "haha", "huhu")
);

$array02 = array(
    0 => array("haha", "welt", "dich"),
    1 => array("hallo", "mag", "nicht"),
    2 => array("du", "ich", "huhu")
);

$array03 = array(
    0 => array("haha", "haha", "dich"),
    1 => array("dich", "mag", "mag"),
    2 => array("du", "ich", "haha")
);

function get_similar_items_count() {
    $arrs = func_get_args();
    foreach ($arrs as &$arr) {
        while (list($k, $v) = each($arr)) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                array_splice($arr,$k,1,$v);
                next($arr);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($arr);
    $counts = array();
    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        foreach (array_count_values($arr) as $k => $v) {
            if ($v) {
                if (!isset($counts[$k])) {
                    $counts[$k]  = $v;
                } else {
                    $counts[$k] += $v;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
    return $counts;
}

print_r(get_similar_items_count($array01,$array02,$array03));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [hallo] => 2
    [welt] => 2
    [du] => 3
    [ich] => 3
    [mag] => 4
    [dich] => 4
    [nicht] => 2
    [haha] => 5
    [huhu] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count(array_intersect($array01[0],$array02[0]));
```

Possibly `foreach()` through bot arrays & sum it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, my understanding is you want to compare all the values in the first array to the second array.  IOW all words within all subarrays of array1 should be compared to all words of all subarrays of array2

```
$array01 = array(
    0 => array("hallo", "welt", "du", "ich"),
    1 => array("mag", "dich"),
    2 => array("nicht", "haha", "huhu")
);

$array02 = array(
    0 => array("haha", "welt", "dich"),
    1 => array("hallo", "mag", "nicht"),
    2 => array("du", "ich", "huhu")
);

$t_array01 = array();
foreach($array01 as $arr) {
  $t_array01 = array_merge($t_array01,$arr);
}
$t_array02 = array();
foreach($array02 as $arr) {
  $t_array02 = array_merge($t_array02,$arr);
}

$common = array_intersect($t_array01,$t_array02);
```

`$common` is the array of all words that are in both arrays.  In your example, both arrays contain all of the same words, so it has all of the words. If you just want a count of how many, you can do `count($common)`